# Fetch SSL certificate from local store using java into sslContext object

Tags: java, authentication, ssl, ssl-certificate, keystore

I need to perform a rest call by attaching the local ssl certificate.

I do not have any info about KeyStore. I just know there is a Certificate installed in my PC and I have to use the certificate based on details of certificate like "Serial number", "Issuer" etc which i can see in the certificate details in the personal certificate store.

I need to create SSLConnectionSocketFactory object which can be attached to rest call.

My question is how to create the SSLContext object?

```
  SSLContext sslContext;// How to create this object and pass it to sslSocketFactory.

  HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE; 
  SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = new  SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext, hostnameVerifier);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the `SSLContext` instance using this code snippet.

```
// Load Certificate
CertificateFactory certificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
Certificate certificate = certificateFactory.generateCertificate(new FileInputStream(new File("CERTIFICATE_LOCATION")));

// Create TrustStore
KeyStore trustStoreContainingTheCertificate = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
trustStoreContainingTheCertificate.load(null, null);

trustStoreContainingTheCertificate.setCertificateEntry("ANY_CERTIFICATE_ALIAS", certificate);

// Create SSLContext
TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
trustManagerFactory.init(trustStoreContainingTheCertificate);

SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
sslContext.init(null, trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), null);

SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
System.out.println(sslSocketFactory);
```

Comment: How do I create the " trustStoreContainingTheCertificate"?

Comment: Can I get LayeredConnectionSocketFactory() of org.apache.http.conn.socket.LayeredConnectionSocketFactory instead of SSLSocketFactory at the end?